# Export PDF from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, export, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export a table in PDF, but I have a foreach and I want to export all data from foreach, but is not working for all, just for a row.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $html = '<div class="table-scrollable">
                    <table id="posts" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="body"><tr>
                            <td>'
            . $post->id . ' 
                            </td>
                            <td>' .
            $post->name .
            '</td>
                            <td>'
            . $post->title .
            '</td> 
                </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>';
}
return PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->download('my_pdf');
```

Comment: In every iteration you overwrite `$html`. You probably want to append to it, right?

Comment: Yes..but I don't know how.

Comment: Have a read about string operators at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @Sulde1985 use `$html .= '...` instead of `$html = '...`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin if i'm using $html with dot. I'm getting this error "Undefined variable: html"

Comment: @Sulde1985 just create it before `foreach()` with `$html = '';`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin after that, i'm getting " The localhost page isn’t working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside foreach construct you override your `$html` variable, you need to initialize `$html` before `foreach` and add to end of string your html using Concatenation assignment  `.=`

```
$html = '';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $html .= '<div class="table-scrollable">
                        <table id="posts" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="body"><tr>
                                <td>'
                . $post->id . ' 
                                </td>
                                <td>' .
                $post->name .
                '</td>
                                <td>'
                . $post->title .
                '</td> 
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>';
}
return PDF::load($html, 'A4', 'portrait')->download('my_pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that's what i'm doing and i'm getting this error "The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request."

Comment: I have too much data, that was the problem, but the solution is good. Thanks to all for help.